# Navigator.app.exitApp()/navigator.device.exitApp() crashing with error on 3.0.0 only

Tags: cordova, cordova-3

I was wondering if any of you were aware of, or knew of a solution to this issue. Basically I have this function here:

```
  function onDeviceReady() {
     document.addEventListener("backbutton", function() {
     if (getObj("btnBack") != null){
                pui.click("btnBack");
             }
     else{ 
        navigator.device.exitApp();
     }
     }, false);
  }
```

where pui.click() is just something defined on my end. So this function gets called whenever the back button on my android device is pressed; on 2.9 and all versions below if this reaches a point on the app where the btnBack obj is not present, it calls navigator.device.exitApp() (or navigator.app.exitApp() I switched between the two to see if that would fix my issue) and the app closes just fine. Now with 3.0.0 I get the following fatal exception in Eclipse:

08-16 15:23:27.015: E/AndroidRuntime(22715): android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token android.os.BinderProxy@422635a8 is not valid; is your activity running?

Anyone know whats going on here? I grabbed my application with the previous version from the android market and it works just fine with the back button.

Edit:

Still having this issue months later. My activity is unchanged (there is another package being imported here that I did not include but otherwise this is my activity's source:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import org.apache.cordova.*;

public class PUIClient extends CordovaActivity 
{
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        super.init();
        // Set by <content src="index.html" /> in config.xml
        super.loadUrl(Config.getStartUrl());
        //super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html")
    }
}
```

Edit:

Here is the logcat screenshot; it loosk like this is being caused by the onMessage call internally. It seems something internally is trying to send that message while the application is closing down. 
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking through the Notifications.java file that comes from the Dialogs plugin, I found that adding the following isFinishing() check has solved my problem. I am not sure what is causing a notification to be executed when I quit the application, but a simple check as highlighted in my screenshot negates that last alert and my app closes smoothly. I had this issue for months starting at version 2.9; hopefully this helps someone in a similar bind. 
[image: See red highlighted box]

Answer (score 1):

Without the full code it is hard to tell where the problem is :(

Check if you are making some alerts or calls inside `getObj("btnBack")`.

Did you change something iside your activity?

Comment: My activity is basically unchanged; I have included it in the original post.

Comment: I forgot to add, getObj does not contain any alerts or calls; it is simply a wrapper that runs document.getElementById() and performs a few simple checks.

Comment: I have also included my logcat screenshot.

Comment: I found a solution to my problem in case you were interested. See answer.